# How to know if table fields match with numbers?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have a table in a SQLServer database that simulate a bingo card. In total are 25 fields that represents the numbers on the card: `n1, n2, n3, ..., n25`

Similar to imagem below:
[image]

Let's say I to raffle the numbers 5, 28 e 67, how to do a select to get if the card save on the table match with the fields and numbers?

The result would be like

`Card | Matchs
    1 |       3
    2 |       3
    3 |       2
    4 |       1
    5 |       1
    6 |       1`

Any suggest? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should fix your data models so the values are in columns rather than rows.  SQL Server makes it pretty easy to unpivot the numbers using `apply`, so you can get around this:

```
select b.*, s.cnt
from bingo b cross apply
     (select count(*) as cnt
      from (values (n1), (n2), . . ., (n25)) v(n)
      where n in (5, 28, 67)
     ) s;
```

Fill in the rest of the numbers in the `. . .`.